# Set the Button Text according to Resource File in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, internationalization

I am an Amateur Visual C# Programmer.
I want to implement the concept of **I18N** in my project.
(Similar to **strings.xml** in Android)

I have added 2 String Resources in my Resource File.

And I have added 2 Buttons in my form.
Now, I want the text of the Button to be the string value from the Resource file.

Please help.

Adhish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using windows form, you can use this procedure. 
Open the properties menu of the form in the design. Select the option "Language" and choose the language that you want. 
Selecting a different language will create automatically a new file resource with the label for the language selected.
The file .resx will the same name of the form plus the initial of the language used.

Comment: Thanks. Never thought it would be so easy. Haha :)

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on your UI framework. The following solution is for WinForms, but you can implement it (without MVVM) in WPF as well.

1. Create a button in the designer.
2. Register to the Load event of the form by double clicking it. (Right click on the form => properties => click the events button => search for the Load event)
3. In the load event, initialize the text of the button with the string from the resources.

Your code should look something like this:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.Text = MyResources.ButtonText;
}
```